# custom jQuery plugin to work on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a jQuery plugin. The problem is when i assign this plugin to single element it
works properly. When i assign for 2 different elements then plugin will not work as expected.

Issue:

When i click on list that dynamically appended by plugin, i was trying to print the particular element id, but i get both element id's if i click on either one.

Result:

```
Object[input#a1]
Object[input#a2]
```

Example HTML:

```
<div><input type="text" id="a1" /></div> 
<div><input type="text" id="a2" /></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#a1").xyz();     $("#a2").xyz();

<div>
    <input type="text" id="a1" />
    <div class=".xyz-list">some text</div> // dynamically created by plugin
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="a2" />
    <div class=".xyz-list">some text</div> // dynamically created by plugin
</div>
```

Sample Code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.xyz = function(opt) {
        var defaults = $.extend({
            select: 4,
            error: null
        }, opt);

        return this.each(function() {
            var ele = $(this);

                // APPEND LIST TO ELEMENT'S PARENT
                ele.parent().append('<div class="xyz-list">SOME TEXT</div>');

                // WHEN CLICK ON LIST
                $(".xyz-list").live('click', function() {
                    var current_list = $(this);
                    console.log(ele);
                    return false;
                });
        });   
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny jQuery version 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are binding the handlers in a loop, so each existing element will have more than one event handler attached to it, you should bind the handler after the `.each()` call.

```
return this.each(function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    // APPEND LIST TO ELEMENT'S PARENT
    ele.parent().append('<div class="xyz-list">SOME TEXT</div>');
}).parent().on('click', 'xyz-list', function() {
   // Do something:
}).end();
```

Another option is attaching the handler directly to the element when it is generated:

```
$("<div/>", {
   "class": "xyz-list",
    click: function() {
        var current_list = $(this);
        console.log(ele);
        return false;
    },
    text: 'SOME TEXT'
}).appendTo(ele.parent());
```

Also note that `.live()` method is deprecated you should use `.on()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem try with `class` and `data-id` attributes.

```
<div><input type="text" class="createNew" data-id="a1" /></div> 
<div><input type="text" class="createNew" data-id="a2" /></div>
```